# find rows in table with same input as user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `personalities`  in this table i store `user_id` and `personality_id`

When a user signs up, they select different personalities by ID which then gets put into this table.

I am trying to run a query, that will find all other users that match the same personality_id as the logged in user.

So for example my table would look like this:

```
 id user_id  personality_id
 1  3049     1
 2  3049     4
 4  3049     7
 5  3049     2
 6  3056     5
 7  3056     7
 8  3046     3
 9  3046     10
 10  3049    4
 11  3022    11
 1  3022     12
```

Let's imagine the logged in user is `3049` it should return the user_id's `3056` `3049` as there is a matching personality_id found.

What's the best query to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could self-join the table on `personality_id` and use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates, like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.user_id
FROM personalities p
INNER JOIN personalities p1 ON p.personality_id = p1.personality_id
WHERE p.user_id = 3049
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wY47DJKh734dqLiP6VrFcq/0)** with your sample data returns:

```
| user_id |
| ------- |
| 3049    |
| 3056    |
```

PS : if you want not to return the id of the original user (here, `3049`), then you can add anoter join condition, like:

```
INNER JOIN personalities p1 
    ON p.personality_id = p1.personality_id AND p1.user_id != p.user_id
```

---

An alternative is tu use a `IN` condition with a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM personalities
WHERE personality_id IN (
    SELECT personality_id FROM personalities WHERE user_id = 3049
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wY47DJKh734dqLiP6VrFcq/2)**

Comment: This is perfect, although, is there a way to not return 3049, as that's the logged in user? return all results except from 3049? or would that be some PHP code i'll need to run on front end?

Comment: @JackDaniels: sure - I updated my answer accordingly for the first query. You could also modify the seconde query, of course, by adding a condition to the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do a `in` query...

the following is pseudo code

Table 1:

> Select personality_id from personalities where user_id = 3049 as Table t1;

Table 2:

> Select user_id from personalities where personality_id in t1;